# random number generator from a range for continuos analysis

Tags: java

I can create random numbers from a range using

```
Random rand = new Random();
int num = rand.nextInt(10);
System.out.println("Generated Random Number between 0 to 10 is : " + num);
```

But if i need the next random number generated to be a part of the range `minus` the already generated one, will keeping the above statement in a loop will suffice?

Also I need to stop once i exhaust all the number from the range.

For eg,

The code gives me a random number between [0-10],

`1st - 4` - range {[0-10]}

`2nd - 9` - range {[0-10]-4}

`3rd - 8` - range {[0-10]-4,9}

..

..

`10th - 10` - range {[0-10]-[0-9]}

Will this function output from [Range]{this is my requirement} or (Range)? Or is there any better alternative solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to:

- put the numbers (0 to 10) in a list
- call [`Collections.shuffle()` on that list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)
- loop over the list

Something like:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10);
Collections.shuffle(numbers);
System.out.println(numbers);
```

You can even [provide a random generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) for the shuffling operation if the default doesn't suit you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible.  Try to remember the numbers you already generatedin a list and use it to generate more random numbersuntil you find one that is not in your list.